# Item clic with ListView Android don't work correctly

Tags: android, listview

I can not get the correct screen open.
I have the following code, and I also added the corresponding class in the manifest.
Please, if you can give me some idea.
Thank you.

```
listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    ListAdapter adp = (ListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();

    //lista.get(position);
    Seccion s = lista.get(Integer.parseInt(adp.getItem(position).toString()));

    if (s.getTitle().contains("Estudiar")) {
      //sel.setText("Seleccionado el del if"+ s.getTitle());
      Intent i = new Intent(LiverpoolguideActivity.this,tipoListado.class);
      startActivity(i);
    }
  }
});
```

The code tipoListado.class :

```
package jorgechu.com.liverpoolguide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import jorgechu.com.liverpoolguide.Secciones.Seccion;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class tipoListado extends Activity {

  public class LiverpoolguideActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.listadotipo);
    }
  }
}
```

And the code screen xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewListadoTipo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tipo:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewType"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put some logging into your code and help us help yourself. What line does it get to? Does the item click fire? Does it hit the if? Do you get a crash? What does your LogCat say. Come on you should do all of this before you post on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusable views inside a ListView item will disable the ability to select ListView items. Applying android:focusable="false" to the TextView will allow OnItemClick to work again.